# How to split a table to a group of tables based on a criteria?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a table named "A" contain the following data

**Table A:**

```
type   name  age
-----------------
dog     a     2
bird    b     1
dog     c     3
cat     d     2
bird    e     2
```

I am aiming to split this table to a group of tables based on a specific criteria like "Type" to be as follows:

**Table 1:**

```
type   name  age
-----------------
dog    a     2
dog    c     3
```

**Table 2:**

```
type   name  age
-----------------
bird    b     1
bird    e     2
```

**Table 3:**

```
type   name  age
-----------------
cat     d     2
```

Comment: mysql or sql-server ???

Comment: @SimoOs . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  There is no obvious reason to split one table into three in this way.  Can you motivate what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Better way to create a type table, and replace all types with typeID

Comment: @GordonLinoff let say i have Animal Care Center contain department that handle only one type of animal,  but i have a data table of all animals in the center. and i need to send to each department the only data they concerned.

Comment: @SimoOs why would it not be sufficient to query `tableA` and filter on  the `type` column for each department?

Answer (score 1):

could try using create view

```
   create view table1 as 
   select type, name, age 
   from table_a 
   where type ='dog'
   ;

  create view table2 as 
   select type, name, age 
   from table_a 
   where type ='bird'
   ;

   create view table3 as 
   select type, name, age 
   from table_a 
   where type ='cat '
   ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well assuming the other tables were already created, you would just need an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`, e.g. for `table1`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (type, name, age)
SELECT type, name, age
FROM tableA
WHERE type = 'dog';
```

*However*, doing what you suggest is a step in the wrong direction, most likely, because your current table would be easier to use.  If you instead go with many tables all storing data which is logically very similar, then it will be much harder to do anything.

Comment: i already used that. but its takes for ever. not motioning the errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write a procedure with a while loop where iterator will be the count of Types. Then create a table for each type separately with same columns and insert data into the table all within the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this whith a `cursor` and `SELECT INTO`:

```sql
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @TableCounter INT;
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(20);

SET @TableCounter = 1;


DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT type 
FROM Table_A

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Type

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
      PRINT @Type
      SET @TableName = CONCAT('Table_', @TableCounter)
      SET @SQL = 'SELECT * INTO '+ @TableName +' FROM Table_A WHERE Type = ''' + @Type+''''

      EXEC (@SQL)

      SET @TableCounter = @TableCounter + 1;

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Type 
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I think this code could be short with a nested sentence, but works.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid code duplication and creating unnecessary tables I would create a **table-valued UDF** (User Defined Function) that takes the criteria as input parameter (`type` in your case) and returns the original table filtered accordingly:

```
create function GetNameByType
(   
    @type varchar(50)
)
returns table 
as
return 
(
    select [type], [name], [age]
    from A
    where [type] = @type
)
GO
```

Now you can invoke the function `GetNameByType` with different `type` values and you can use it as a table.

Query 1:

```
select * from GetNameByType('dog')
```

results for query 1:

[image]

query 2:

```
select * from GetNameByType('bird')
```

results for query 2:

[image]

query 3:

```
select * from GetNameByType('cat')
```

results for query 3:

[image]

More info on table-valued UDFs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).